# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `weight` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, html

I have this task where I am to build a BMI calculator based on specific instructions. I  have followed all the instructions but seem to be getting something wrong. The instruction  for this stage which I have seemingly followed says:

> Step 1
>   Just above `getSelectedUser`, create a `computeBMI` arrow function that expects a user parameter, but immediately de-strctures it to the `weight`, `height`, and `country` properties.
>   Step 2
>   Go back to `letsCalculateBMI` and get it to obtain the selected value from the SELECT element, pass that value to a `getSelectedUser` function call, which should return the `user object` for the selected value. This user object should be assigned to a `user` variable.
>
> At this point, `letsCalculateBMI` is ready to calculate the user's BMI. It should do this by calling `computeBMI` and passing it user. It then sets the return value from invoking `computeBMI` to a `bmi` variable, which is finally set as the text content of the PARAGRAPH within the #outcome DIV
>
> BMEye calculates BMI with an advanced algorithm! BMEye has the notion of countries with the healthiest diet and they are Chad, Sierra Leone, Mali, Gambia, Uganda, Ghana, Senegal, Somalia, Ivory Coast, and Isreal If the user is from any of these countries, then the calculated BMI figure is multipled by 0.82, bringing it down a little.
>
> Step 3
>   Following the guide and hints above, get `computeBMI` to use the user's weight, height, and country to calculate and return the BMI value for the user.

Everything seems to work fine when I select a user but the challenge gives me an error `Awwww snap! Your BMI calculation is not correct. Review the instructions and continue`

```js
const users = [];

const countriesWithLowerBmi = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", "Uganda", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "Isreal"];

const featToMeter = 0.3048;

const bmiCountryRatio = 0.82;

const computeBMI = ({
  weight,
  height,
  country
}) => {

  const heightInMeters = height * featToMeter;
  let BMI = weight / (heightInMeters ^ 2);

  if (countriesWithLowerBmi.includes(country))
    BMI *= bmiCountryRatio;

  return Math.round(BMI, 2);
};

const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
  return users.find(({
    id
  }) => id === userId);
};

const displaySelectedUser = ({
  target
}) => {
  const user = getSelectedUser(target.value);
  const properties = Object.keys(user);

  properties.forEach(prop => {
    const span = document.querySelector(`span[data-${prop}-value]`);
    if (span) {
      span.textContent = user[prop];
    }
  })
}

const letsCalculateBMI = () => {

  const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;

  const user = getSelectedUser(value);

  const bmi = computeBMI(user);

  document.querySelector('.bmi-text').innerHTML = bmi
};

const powerupTheUI = () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('#oracle');

  const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');

  select.addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);

  button.addEventListener('click', letsCalculateBMI);
};

const displayUsers = (users) => {
  users.forEach(user => {
    const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');
    const option = document.createElement('option');

    option.text = user.name;
    option.value = user.id;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
};


const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
  users.push({
    age: 40,
    weight: 75,
    height: 6,
    country: 'Nigeria',
    name: 'Charles Odili',
    id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
  }, {
    age: 23,
    weight: 68,
    height: 6,
    country: 'Nigeria',
    name: 'Simpcy',
    id: 'gibb12erish'
  });

  displayUsers(users);
};

const startApp = () => {
  powerupTheUI();
  fetchAndDisplayUsers();
};

startApp();
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select class="select-text">
    <option disabled selected>Select User</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="user-photo">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Placeholder">
</div>

<div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-age>Age :</span>
    <span class="value" data-age-value>23</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-height>Height :</span>
    <span class="value" data-height-value>169</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-weight>Weight :</span>
    <span class="value" data-weight-value>68</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-gender>Gender :</span>
    <span class="value" data-gender-value>Female</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-country>Country :</span>
    <span class="value" data-country-value>Nigerian</span>
  </p>
</div>

<button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">
      Calculate BMI
    </button>
<div id="outcome">
  <h5 class="mdc-typography--headline5">
    BMI
  </h5>
  <p class="bmi-text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code runs fine when you select a user from the dropdown. You only get the error when you haven't selected a user yet, because you're calling 'computeBmi' with an undefined variable

Comment: The challenge is in stages and for some reason I cannot seem to pass that stage

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `computeBMI` if `getSelectedUser` can't find a user.

```
const letsCalculateBMI = () => {
  const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;
  const user = getSelectedUser(value);
  if (user) {
    const bmi = computeBMI(user);
    document.querySelector('.bmi-text').innerHTML = bmi
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.bmi-text').innerHTML = '';
};
```

Comment: Both your and my answer are correct. One should do both parallelly.

Comment: Don't change the question after you get valid answers. If you have a new problem, post a different question.

Comment: Basically what I had was already running, I was only being more specific to get a useful answer.

Comment: Your edited question was not specific enough. You didn't explain what's wrong with your result, just that the online judge rejected it. We're not going to read through all your code to figure out whether your algorithm is correct. You need to learn how to debug programs yourself if you want to be a successful programmer.

Comment: [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`const stars = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", "Uganda", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "and Isreal"];`

```
  const myComputeBMI = ({ weight, height, country }) => {
    const hInMeters = height * 0.3048;
    const value = (weight / (hInMeters * hInMeters)) 
      * (stars.includes(country) ? 0.82 : 1);
    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Solve this by giving a default value for the destructuring:

```
const computeBMI = ({
  weight,
  height,
  country
} = {weight: 0, height: 0, country: 0}) => {/*...*/}
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is new
```

```js
console.clear();
const users = [];

const countriesWithLowerBmi = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", "Uganda", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "Isreal"];

const featToMeter = 0.3048;

const bmiCountryRatio = 0.82;

const computeBMI = ({
  weight,
  height,
  country
} = {weight: 0, height: 0, country: 0}) => {

  const heightInMeters = height * featToMeter;
  let BMI = weight / (heightInMeters ^ 2);

  if (countriesWithLowerBmi.includes(country))
    BMI *= bmiCountryRatio;

  return Math.round(BMI, 2);
};

const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
  return users.find(({
    id
  }) => id === userId);
};

const displaySelectedUser = ({
  target
}) => {
  const user = getSelectedUser(target.value);
  const properties = Object.keys(user);

  properties.forEach(prop => {
    const span = document.querySelector(`span[data-${prop}-value]`);
    if (span) {
      span.textContent = user[prop];
    }
  })
}

const letsCalculateBMI = () => {

  const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;

  const user = getSelectedUser(value);

  const bmi = computeBMI(user);

  document.querySelector('.bmi-text').innerHTML = bmi
};

const powerupTheUI = () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('#oracle');

  const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');

  select.addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);

  button.addEventListener('click', letsCalculateBMI);
};

const displayUsers = (users) => {
  users.forEach(user => {
    const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');
    const option = document.createElement('option');

    option.text = user.name;
    option.value = user.id;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
};


const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
  users.push({
    age: 40,
    weight: 75,
    height: 6,
    country: 'Nigeria',
    name: 'Charles Odili',
    id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
  }, {
    age: 23,
    weight: 68,
    height: 6,
    country: 'Nigeria',
    name: 'Simpcy',
    id: 'gibb12erish'
  });

  displayUsers(users);
};

const startApp = () => {
  powerupTheUI();
  fetchAndDisplayUsers();
};

startApp();
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select class="select-text">
    <option disabled selected>Select User</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="user-photo">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Placeholder">
</div>

<div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-age>Age :</span>
    <span class="value" data-age-value>23 years</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-height>Height :</span>
    <span class="value" data-height-value>169cm</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-weight>Weight :</span>
    <span class="value" data-weight-value>68kg</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-gender>Gender :</span>
    <span class="value" data-gender-value>Female</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="prop" data-country>Country :</span>
    <span class="value" data-country-value>Nigerian</span>
  </p>
</div>

<button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">
      Calculate BMI
    </button>
<div id="outcome">
  <h5 class="mdc-typography--headline5">
    BMI
  </h5>
  <p class="bmi-text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I just changed it back. We answered your question, you shouldn't change it to a different question.